# While doing clusteing in R using dtwclust , how can I retrieve / label the mebership of the clusterss formed by tsclust?

Tags: r, time-series, cluster-analysis

while using dtwclust package for clustering time series, the data is organised with each time series as a row. However while preparing the list of time series ( using tslist) we need to drop the row names ( the identifier of each of the individual timer series )
How can I retrieve / label the members of each cluster formed ?

I am a newbie and have presently no clue on this

Comment: Hi Kshitij, welcome to SO. Your question requires additional information in order to provide a working solution. Please review [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) and update your question. Thanks